# how to understand the x in ${CONFIG+x}

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

The code is below,

```
if [ -z ${CONFIG+x} ]; then
CONFIG=/usr/local/etc/config.ini
else
CONFIG=$(realpath $CONFIG)
fi
```

Can someone tell me what "x" exactly mean?

Answer (score 4):

It means that if the variable `$CONFIG` is set, use the value `x`, otherwise use the null (empty) string.

The test `-z` checks whether the following argument is empty, so if `$CONFIG` is not set, the `if` branch will be taken.

Testing it out (with `$a` previously unset):

```
$ echo "a: '${a+x}'"
a: ''
$ a='any other value'    
$ echo "a: '${a+x}'"
a: 'x'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the [*parameter expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_01) features defined for the POSIX shell.  The simplest is just a variable which is substituted, `${parameter}`, while the others have an embedded operator telling what to do with an optional parameter versus an optional *word*, e.g, "${parameter*OP*word}"

For this particular case, *parameter* is `CONFIG`, *OP* is `+` and *word* is `x`:

- if the parameter is *Set and Not Null*, the *word*'s value is used, otherwise
- if the parameter is *Set and Null*, the *word*'s value is used, otherwise
- a null value is used

A null value for a shell variable is from an explicit assignment, e.g.,

```
CONFIG=
```

If a variable has never been assigned to, it is *unset*.  You can make a variable *unset* using that keyword:

```
unset CONFIG
```

There are separate tests for *Set and Not Null* and *Set and Null* because the standard lists eight operators.  For six of those, the *parameter*'s value would be used if it is *Set and Not Null*.

In substitution, you cannot see a difference between an unset and null value.  Some shells (such as bash) define additional types of parameter expansion; this question is more general.

Comment: Nice, I thought this was bash-only.

Comment: I don't have them memorized, but think it's worth pointing out whether it is or not, as a check on portability.

Comment: You described the behavior of `${a:+x}`, not `${a+x}`. Without the colon, `x` is used if `a` is set at all, to either a null or non-null value.